# php if else statement within a select box

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am working on a piece that allows user to create an article, but there are some restricted for an admin, which i identify as SgroupId 1. Now when I log in with my admin code, i realize i still cant post everything, except for what I identified in loadTypeUsers. I know i get the value of Sgroup1 with me, since the admin panel loads in the bar below. Also when I echo the value I get the return of 1, which should be fine.

But when I try to load the dropdown in my popup, it wont give me the full list. Instead, it loads just the list I specified in the LoadTypeUsers. Can somebody help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

~Dorv

```
function MakeArticleTypeDropdown(){
        echo "<select name='ArticleTypeId'>";

        if($SgroupId == 1 || $SgroupId == 1){ 
            $results = LoadType();
        }
        else
        {
            $results = LoadTypeUsers();
        }

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
            echo "<option value='".$row['ArticleTypeId']."'>"
                            .$row['ArticleTypeName']."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }
```

This is tucked in the ArticleFunction.php file

```
function LoadTypeUsers(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Articletype limit 1,3;";
    $resultaat=SendQuery($query);
    return $resultaat;
}

    function LoadType(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Articletype;";
    $resultaat=SendQuery($query);
    return $resultaat;
}
```

This is tucked in the Sentry.php file

```
session_start();
$UserName = $_SESSION['username'];

$result = mysql_query("select * from user where username='".$UserName."'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $UserId = $row['UserId'];
                $CharacterName = $row['CharacterName'];
                $UserName = $row['UserName'];
                $SgroupId = $row['SgroupId'];
            };
```

Comment: Where does the `$SgroupId` varialbe should come from in the `MakeArticleTypeDropdown` function? From here it seem to be undefined.

Comment: either pass it to the function MakeArticleTypeDropdown($SgroupId) or use global $SgroupId; inside the function so it has access to the outside value;

Comment: rabble rabble `mysql_*` rabble rabble open to sql injection rabble rabble strict type-checking rabble rabble row is open to xss rabble

Comment: just curiousity : why this `if($SgroupId == 1 || $SgroupId == 1)`? (repeated) or its a typo!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$SgroupId is not defined in the function MakeArticleTypeDropdown() so it will always goes in else condition .Try something as follows

```
MakeArticleTypeDropdown($SgroupId)
{
//-----------your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem. I feel really dumb I overlooked to shoot the groupId to the function! thank you very much

Comment: it happens often with us that is why such community and forums are there to help each other.thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 3):

first of all, I don't see you passing the value of `$SgroupId` to `MakeArticleTypeDropdown()`. Maybe you have an scope problem and you're checking a variable $SgroupId that isn't set inside the function?

second: `($SgroupId == 1 || $SgroupId == 1)` What is that `||` for?

Comment: it's a typo, sorry, it should have been ($SgroupId == 1 || $SgroupId == 2)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `LIMIT` clause should be a `WHERE` clause.

i.e.

`SELECT * FROM Articletype WHERE SgroupId = 1 OR SgroupId = 3`

and perhaps the line

```
if($SgroupId == 1 || $SgroupId == 1){
```

should read

```
if($SgroupId == 1 || $SgroupId == 3){
```

Comment: I tried it with a where clause, but it made the query a tat long, and its just i need statements 2,3 and 4 out of the table. I thought this was the right solution and it works for me. The table itself has no SgroupId linked to it. The articleType table just defines the numbers within the article table.

Comment: The `LIMIT` just limits the number of rows retrieved. What was implied is not that. Perhaps an edit of the question (please do not edit the existing text but add further imformation).

Comment: i gotcha, i will look into this, but I can tell you that the ArticleType table just has 2 fiels, which is ArticleTypeId (which runs to the Article table) and the definition of each Id, 1 being announcement, 2 being article and so on. So I dont understand in this case where the SgroupId from you comes in. You want me to add another fieldset in my database where I state that that one is usable being each group? Sorry, cause you lost me there, Ed.

Comment: Just a hunch that the PHP variable name is the same as the column name and hence the two functions, one with `LIMIT` would use that.